# How to Make SSIS Package Fail When There's No Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a very simple package of SQL `Data Flow Task` that executes a query and deletes the result.

Is there a way to make my package fails when there's no result in the query? I try adding `Execute SQL Task` to get the result Count, but I'm not sure how to make it fail when result Count = 0.

Answer (score 3):

Some SQL like this should do it:

```
DECLARE @CNT INT;
SELECT @CNT = COUNT(*) FROM Table;
IF @CNT = 0 RAISERROR('Error',17,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Script Task to achieve this:

1. Use the `Execute SQL Task` to store the result Count in a package variable
2. Add a Script Task to check the variable value and fails if value equal zero

*First you have to add the variable to the Script `ReadOnly Variables`*

*Assuming that the variable name is `@[User::Variable]`*

```
    Public Sub Main()

        If Dts.Variables.Item("User::Variable").Value = 0 Then

            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
        Else
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

        End If


    End Sub
```